# If I have iPhone SDK 3.2 is there any way I can use 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, ipad

The current 3.2 SDK doesn't seem to contain 3.1.3 - how do I get it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the 3.1.3 SDK and install it in another location if you want to keep the 3.2.2 beta, ie /Developer313

See image below for where to click to enter new install place.

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100203-ny1ahei187k36t1aihf8k97crs.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100203-ny1ahei187k36t1aihf8k97crs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to download the new 3.1.3 SDK. In addition, Apple recommends against submitting apps to the App Store that were built using 3.2, even if they're targeting 3.x.